# Translating Elementary @Weblate issues

Tags: translation

Firstly, I can't save translations, the button states that I don't have the required privileges. Above it says "There is currently no active translator for this translation, please consider becoming a translator as your suggestion might otherwise remain unreviewed"

How do I become reviewer/coordinator(?) for my selected localisation language?

Comment: Me too. I can not translate anything

Comment: Have you tried going through this route instead?  https://l10n.elementary.io/projects/

Comment: The main advice is here: https://elementary.io/docs/translation-guide#translation-guide

Comment: Hi,@SamMorrowDrums I've read it. The thing is I want to save those translations, now all I can do is suggest. Also, as per the message in the question above, these suggestions aren't going to be in the translated strings because supposedly they might remain unreviewed.

Comment: @Panwar108 there is another link on the EOS homepage to chat with Elementary Translators. I'd suggest you ask there: https://ele-l10n.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtMjkwMjI2Mzk5ODQxLWM3NWZlMjMxMTUyNzg0MjdiNTdkYTM5ZDA3NzE5YTIwMzZmZjhmZjg0MzQwMGE5MjVhMGU2Yjk2MDU1MGZiYTU

Comment: I found that link here: https://elementary.io/get-involved#translations

Comment: @Panwar108 OK I've created this issue, to improve the documentation. Hopefully you can help with it if you find out more info from the Slack chat. https://github.com/elementary/website/issues/1932